# How do I find the number of items in this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If set $A$ represents all integers from 10 to 100, inclusive; set $B$ represents all integers that are multiples of 3; and set $C$ represents all squares of integers, then how can I find how many numbers are in the set $(A \cap B) \setminus C$ *mathematically*? I know that there must be 30 numbers in the set $A \cap B $, but unfortunately, I don't know where to go from there without writing out all the numbers or writing a program to figure it out for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really a "mathematical" way to do it, just reason it out.

|$A\cap B$| = 30, so it might be helpful to find out $|A\cap B \cap C|$ and then subtract this from 30 to get your answer. You're finding out what you don't want and subtracting it from the total to get what you want.

Since the perfect squares start at 4 and end at 10, there are seven possibilities for perfect squares in your set, but among them, the only ones that are multiples of 3 are 36 and 81. Therefore, you can throw these two out, and get $30 - 2 = 28$.

Comment: That makes sense. I counted 7 squares, though: 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100.

Comment: Whoops, yes, 7, including 4.